# Find nested object by value and return the found objects key

Tags: javascript

This has probably been asked quite a few times before but I'm having trouble finding a decent solution.

I have the JSON result of a mongo query kinda resembling this:

```
var data = [{ _id: 123, name: "Test"}, { _id: 124, name: "Test2" }]
```

This is a very simple version of the data I have, I need to be able to find and object in the array that matches the "_id" property something like

```
data.find({ _id: 123 }); // returns 0
data.find({ _id: 124 }); // returns 1
```

If anyone knows a good solid solution to this it will be greatly appreciated.

## Updated:

I've used the answer provided by @Rocket Hazmat to create a neat little module for angular. Since I'm working with objects I wanted a way to query the json in a similar way to mongo.

```
angular.module("myModule").factory("obj", function() {
    return {
        findKey: function(query, data) {
            for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i +=1) {
                var item = data[i],
                    match = true;
                // Check each object
                for (var x in query) {
                    if (item[x] !== data[x]) {
                        match = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // Did it match ?
                if (match) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

I can then use this in my controllers:

```
angular.module("myModule")
    .controller("mainCtrl", ["$scope", "obj", function($scope, $obj) {
        // This would be the result of an ajax request
        $scope.people = [
            { _id: 1, name: "Test1" },
            { _id: 2, name: "Test2" },
            { _id: 3, name: "Test3" }
        ];

        $obj.findKey({ _id: 1, name: "Test1" }, $scope.people); // 0
        $obj.findKey({ _id: 2 }, $scope.people); // 1
        $obj.findKey({ name: "Test2"}, $scope.people); // 1
        $obj.findKey({ _id: 3, name: "Test3" }, $scope.people); // 2
        $obj.findKey({ _id: 3, name: "Test1" }, $scope.people); // false
    }]);
```

This would be buried deep inside a large application and I needed a fast way to get the key of the item so I can easily manipulate the scope

Comment: If you know you are only going to be searching for `_id`, I'd look for something like `data.find(123)` instead since it'll be faster than searching by an object with unknown properties.

Comment: Isn't the outcome right? 0 is the place of _id:123? kind of like data[0]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're gonna need to loop through the array and compare each object to see if it contains the key(s) you're looking for.

Here's something I hacked up quickly.

```
Array.prototype.find = function(obj){
    // Loop through array
    for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++){
        var ele = this[i],
            match = true;
        // Check each object
        for(var x in obj){
            if(ele[x] !== obj[x]){
                match = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        // Did it match?
        if(match){
            return i;
        }
    }
};
```

Then just run it like you have shown:

```
data.find({ _id: 124 }); // 1
```

Comment: Awesome, this has worked nicely with our project. I can't post the exact code as its part of a larger angular app but I'll post a simpler version adapted from your answer :)

Comment: Glad I could help! :-D

Comment: I've amended my question with my solution ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can extend `Array` object with new functionality by adding a function to the `Array.prototype`, and you can use `this` to refer the the **owner** which calls the function.

Inside the find() method, you can utilize [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function to filter the collection.

```
var data = [{ _id: 123, name: "Test"}, { _id: 124, name: "Test2" }]

Array.prototype.find = function(obj){
    return this.filter(function(item){
        return (item._id === obj._id);
    });
}

var result = data.find({_id: 123});
```

Comment: Good answer, but since this is a place to learn - I would encourage you to answer with some sort of explanation to help for those who need it.

Comment: @peterchon Updated a bit and hope it helps.

Comment: FYI -- `Array.prototype.Filter` is not supported in IE8 and below. [See the support matrix here](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.filter). Not sure if this is an issue for the original poster.

Comment: @lbstr It is available in JS 1.6 and I only consider writing JS for real browsers.

Comment: @sza Unfortunately, IE8 is still very real for many developers. I didn't mean to sound like I was providing that information for you exclusively.

Comment: Yup unfortunately I have to support IE8 :S

Answer (score 0):

Use [JsonPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) with the filter

```
$[?(@._id==123)]
```

to extract the element with id *123*. So you are looking for the function

```
function find(array, id) {
    return jsonPath(array, '$[?(@._id==' + id + ')]');
}
```

Test it with the [JSONPath Online Evaluator](http://ashphy.com/JSONPathOnlineEvaluator/).
Make sure you convert to JSON first:

```
[{ "_id": 123, "name": "Test"}, { "_id": 124, "name": "Test2" }]
```

Comment: Seems like an awesome library, but I just needed something to return the objects key